# Routing Service that Avoids Areas?

Tags: openstreetmap, routing, area, united-states

I'm just starting with GIS, and I'm looking for a routing service that will allow me to avoid given regions on a map, or to build my own router that has this functionality. The site OpenRouteService.org has this capability, but the back-end of this website seems to be down for the last few days. So I'm wondering, what would be your advice for doing this? Either a service that will plot from point A to B given the constraint to avoid a region, or how to build my own version. Or a working clone of openrouteservice? What I've tried is downloading the github page of openrouteservice here:https://github.com/GIScience/openrouteservice. The provided .html gives a working front-end, but I have to say I'm a bit  confused how to start getting the back-end working.

I should mention I'm looking for something that will work in the U.S. northeast. Openroute seems to not have the U.S. in its coverage area currently.

Comment: Last few days there were some problems, as the service was being updated. At the moment, the backend of OpenRouteService is working, at least on my machine. 

You might tried to compute a route which lies outside the [coverage](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/File:ORS_Coverage.png). If you have any further questions regarding OpenRouteService, please contact them using the following email address
openrouteservice at geog.uni-heidelberg.de.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I did try to compute a route in the US, which I see now is outside their coverage for now.

Comment: Any known services or code that will do this for the U.S.?

Comment: As said this seems to be the only applications that support that feature. You might ask the OSM US  community if they opperate seperated service instances with america coverage.

Comment: Here maps seems to offer this https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/example-route-avoiding-an-area.html

Answer (score 4):

You can use [OpenRouteService](http://www.openrouteservice.org) to add custom avoid areas / danger zones etc. The only alternative seems to be BRouter corresponding to the [wiki overview](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/online_routers).

Answer (score 1):

[Brouter-web](http://brouter.de/brouter-web/) offers avoiding areas as an interactive set of circular "nogo" areas with defined centre and radius.

- It is a front-end for the java based back-end [BRouter](http://brouter.de/brouter/profiles2/), that is primarily an Android offline routing service.
- Both [Brouter-web](https://github.com/nrenner/brouter-web) and [BRouter](https://github.com/abrensch/brouter) are Open sources on GitHub.
- It offer various script based routing algorithms, [built-in ones](http://brouter.de/brouter/profiles2/) or [custom ones](https://github.com/poutnikl/Brouter-profiles/wiki).